# Light antivirus that doesn't interfare with Windows firewall

Tags: windows-7, antivirus

My laptop system is Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit (Intel Core i3 CPU).

Most of the antivirus programs slows the system. I've been using Avast free antivirus for a while but then it turned out that Avast interfares with Windows fireawll eventhough I close the feature, so I need another one hopefully that doesn't.

What would you suggest?

Comment: What's wrong with Windows' antivirus?

Comment: Do you mean windows firewall? I don't know any other windows antivirus.

Comment: No, I mean [Security Essentials](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5201)

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just use Microsoft's [Security Essentials](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5201). It works fine on Win 7 and [does reasonably well in antivirus tests](https://www.av-test.org/en/compare-manufacturer-results/). 
If you are not the risk-taking type it is good enough.

I experience no slowdowns because of it. Early in 2016 there was a lot of hassle in combination with Windows Update, where Update would take ages especially if Essentials was also running, but that has been solved.